# How to bind value of type parameter to type of `this`?

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter

```
interface A<T extends B</*?*/>> {
    method(T param);
}

interface B<U extends A> {
    // ...
}
```

In code snippet above how can it be expressed that method `A#method` should only accept parameters that are objects parametrized by type (or its descendants) on which the method is called.

I'd like to achive something like this:

```
interface Vehicle<T extends SteeringDevice</*?*/> {
    default steer(T steeringDevice) {
        // ...
    }
}

interface SteeringDevice<U extends Vehicle> {
    // ...
}

// -----

class Car implements Vehicle<SeeringWheel> {
    // ...
}

class SteeringWheel implements SteeringDevice<Car> {
    // ...
}

// -----

class Bike implements Vehicle<Handlebars> {
    // ...
}

class Handlebars implements SteeringDevice<Bike> {
    // ...
}
```

... where it's possible so safely call `new Car().steer(new SteeringWheel())` but not `new Car().steer(new Handlebars())`.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `<T extends Comparable<T>>`?

Comment: Do you really need `SteeringDevice` to be generic?  If you don't, take off the type parameter and you should be able to get everything to work easily.  If you do, please provide more details about what you're trying to do that requires the type parameter, so that we can help come up with a solution (which may require some refactoring).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
interface Vehicle<T extends SteeringDevice<? extends Vehicle<T>>> {
    default void steer(T steeringDevice) {}
}

interface SteeringDevice<U extends Vehicle<? extends SteeringDevice<U>>> {
    // ...
}
```

This forces the two compatible implementations to cross-reference each other. Changing the argument to an incompatible type will now trigger a compile error in the paired class.

One potential issue with the above is that it allows for multiple implementations of `SteeringDevice<Car>`. You can make the pairing more explicit by adding a self type parameter:

```
interface Vehicle<U extends Vehicle<U, T>, T extends SteeringDevice<T, U>> {
    default void steer(T steeringDevice) {}
}

interface SteeringDevice<T extends SteeringDevice<T, U>, U extends Vehicle<U, T>> {
    // ...
}

class Car implements Vehicle<Car, SteeringWheel> {
    // ...
}

class SteeringWheel implements SteeringDevice<SteeringWheel, Car> {
    // ...
}
```

It's *still* possible to create another implementation of `SteeringDevice<SteeringWheel, Car>`, because Java doesn't have a true self type, but at least it makes the violation more obvious. It also has the advantage of breaking *both* classes on an invalid type argument.